# finding the continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I need to find the value of $a$ for which the function $f(x,y)= \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0) $  and $f(x,y)=a$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$ when continuous along the path $y=b\sqrt{x}$ where $b\neq 0$ and then $f$ is continuous.

The answer I obtained for the first part is $a=-1.$ Is this correct? What about the second part ?

Comment: Your "second part" is not clear. Do you mean making the function $f$ continuous in both variables at all points?

Comment: I think this is what I am asked for yes.

Answer (score 2):

$ f(x) = \frac {x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} $ is not continuous at $(0,0) $ ,

Because if we approach through real axis  $ f(x,0)=1 $ and through imaginary axis $f(0,y)=-1$

Comment: yes but would it be continuous if a =0? since f(x,y) is not continuous when x^2+y^2=0

Comment: Whatever be the value of  'a' the function is not going to become continuous because $ L_1 \neq  L_2  $

Comment: ok then thanks :) do you think the first one is correet please?

Comment: I don't think so !

Comment: do you know how it should be worked out then?

Comment: I think I mentioned it in the answer.!Approach through real axis first(keep imaginary axis zero) then through imaginary axis ( keep real axis zero)